# What are good (state of the art?) methods for automatic grammar correction?

Tags: computational-linguistics

I'm just beginning to study automatic grammar correction, and was wondering what good methods are for this problem.  I have a system that will select spelling candidates for each term, individually, and was considering the following approach for automatic correction: given a window of one, two, or three, leading and trailing terms to each term, select the spelling candidate which maximizes the probability of the terms appearing together.  Move this window over each term in the original document, and copy the results to a new buffer, then update the original document's buffer with the new one and run this algorithm over it.  Finally, repeat the process to convergence or until I surpass some iteration threshold.

Is this a good approach?  If there are better methods, what are they?

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr

The best method for grammar correction would be statistical method. You give your grammar correction engine sources to crawl in the web and use the natural English there. by the occurrence the grammar correction engine would choose "He sits" instead of "He sit".

Take a look at these papers:

- http://www.ru.is/~hrafn/students/MasterThesis_HenrichReuter.pdf
- http://www.panl10n.net/english/final%20reports/pdf%20files/Bangladesh/BAN21.pdf
- http://david.wardpowers.info/Research/AI/papers/199608-sub-SGC.pdf

There are other options like deep learning for grammar, You can take a look at : http://www.deepgrammar.com/

Comment: The method I described is statistical. The system I have will select a subset of terms for correction rather than requiring every term to be considered at every step.  Would you suggest a single pass over the document or multiple?  Also, what window size would you suggest, and would you only consider the leading terms or both them and the trailing terms?  What algorithms are best for selecting the candidates?  E.g. Is maximizing the joint probability over a small window the best selection mechanism or are there better methods (statistical sampling, etc.)?  How would you handle unseen vocab?

Comment: I plan to construct dictionaries and joint probabilities from web sources (Wikipedia, et al.).  I'll read over the links you've provided, thank you for them.  Regarding my questions, if you have experience with grammar correction I'd greatly appreciate your responses.  I'll experiment with different techniques regardless, but your experience could save me a lot of headaches.